# Invalid conversion from 'int' to 'double*'

Tags: c++

I have this line of code:

```
int g = modf(ans*power, 1)*10;
```

And it is giving me the error:

> Invalid conversion from 'int' to 'double*'.

ans is defined as:

```
double ans = 1.0/d;
```

power is defined as:

```
int power = pow(10,x);
```

and the x that power is using is defined as:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 50; x++) {
```

I don't see where I am using a pointer. If you need more code just ask.

(I have also tried making the line of code that causes the error:

```
int g = (int)modf(ans*power, 1)*10;
```

but that did not work either).

Comment: Post a logically complete code (not simply pieces of it) and include the whole error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`modf(ans*power, 1)` is bad

`double smthng = 1.0; modf(ans*power, &smthng)` is good.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/modf

Answer (score 1):

```
modf(double x, double * intpart);
                     ^^^
```

See [modf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/modf/)

Answer (score 1):

`I don't see where I am using a pointer` : you're not, and that
is the problem.  Look at the signature of `modf`:

```
double modf( double, double* );
```

It requires a `double*` as second argument; you're passing it an
`int`.

Comment: @Tomalak There's certainly no requirement that the second argument of `modf` (the `double*`) be an rvalue.  Most of the time it isn't, in fact; it's something like `&someDouble`.  But perhaps you simply meant that to take the address of something, that something must be an rvalue.  (I would have assumed that everyone knew that, but apparently, some compiler authors didn't.)

Comment: No. In fact, that something must _not_ be an rvalue, which is rather the point I was making.

Answer (score -1):

modf expects a pointer to a double as its second argument.  See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/modf/).

Comment: You can't take the address of a literal.